# Object Oriented Programming in ruby

Tags: ruby

Is method an object in Ruby? My friend asked me this question.I read about this in website.But still I didn't understand it.Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be a confusion here due to ambiguity of the term method. Method in the most ordinary sense is not an object. In the following:

```
"foo".upcase
```

the method `upcase` is applied to an object `"foo"`, but `upcase` is not an object, as can be seen by the fact that it cannot stand alone:

```
upcase # => error
```

(Do not confuse this with when it can be considered that the receiver is omitted).

However, there is a class `Method`, whose instances correspond to methods, and are objects. They may also be called methods, but that is not the normal usage of the term method.

Comment: There are other "things" in Ruby that aren't objects either, including operators, blocks, `while`, `for` and no doubt others.

Comment: More precisely, `"foo".upcase` send the *message* `upcase` to the object `"foo"`. If `"foo"` implements a *method* with the same name, it gets invoked.

Comment: @CarySwoveland operators are actually methods, and blocks are objects.

Comment: @Aetherus, if operators were methods, why would we need the term "operator"?

Comment: @Aetherus If blocks were methods, why would we need an ampersand to convert it to/from a proc?

Comment: @Aetherus, `||`, `&&`, `and` are examples of operators as opposed to methods, but I will grant you that the term "operator" is used loosely to include methods such as `+`, `-` and so on. I believe there's a body of thought that Ruby would conform more closely to OO principles if Ruby's "non-method" operators  were in fact methods.

Comment: @Aetherus: Blocks are not objects - they have no methods, nor can any be sent to them in Ruby's syntax. But they can be wrapped in `Proc` objects. Passing blocks into methods is much, much faster than constructing `Proc` objects and passing them as regular parameters; this is largely because blocks do not need to deal with the OO overhead. Similarly, methods are not objects, but can be wrapped in `Method` and `UnboundMethod` objects.

Answer (score 4):

No, they are not.

Methods themselves are a language structure of Ruby, and they are not objects. But there is a class `Method`, whose instances represent methods, and can be called using `Method#call`.

Also, there is another kind of instances - instances of class `UnboundMethod`, which represent methods that are detached from specific objects. They can't be called directly, but can be used in many different ways.

If you are looking for something like Javascript's `function`s, then procs and lambdas are what you want.